# How to use the VuetifyJS time picker component with a text instead of a null/number?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using VueJS and [VuetifyJS](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers#introduction) for a web app. How to use a text for the [time picker component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers#introduction) without getting `12:NaN` in the time picker header? I need to have **SupriseMe** as a text in the textfield and **00:00** as the default in the time picker header.

Here is a CodePen example of the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEEeyg?&editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe keep the v-model `time` at `null` (as recommended by vuetify) and add a placeholder to the text-field.

Edit: to change the placeholder color, you can override the css by adding a new class name:

```
data () {
  return {
    time: null,
    //...
  }
}

<v-text-field
  slot="activator"
  v-model="time"
  label="Picker in dialog"
  prepend-icon="access_time"
  readonly
  placeholder="SurpiseMe"
  class="date-select" //for example
></v-text-field>
```

```css
<style>
  .date-select > .input-group__input > ::placeholder {
    color: black !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the placeholder color? I need to have it the same color as the selected time. (black)